# Pandas/Python Modeling Time-Series, Groups with Different Inputs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to model different scenarios for groups of assets in future years. This is something I have accomplished very tediously in Excel, but want to leverage the large database I have built with Pandas.

Example:

```
annual_group_cost = 0.02

df1:

year  group  x_count  y_count  value
2018   a       2        5      109000
2019   a       0        4      nan
2020   a       3        0      nan
2018   b       0        0      55000
2019   b       1        0      nan
2020   b       1        0      nan
2018   c       5        1      500000
2019   c       3        0      nan
2020   c       2        5      nan

df2:

group  x_benefit  y_cost  individual_avg  starting_value
a       0.2        0.72     1000            109000
b       0.15       0.75     20000           55000
c       0.15       0.70     20000           500000
```

I would like to update the values in df1, by taking the previous year's value (or starting value) and adding the x benefit, y cost, and annual cost. I am assuming this will take a function to accomplish, but I don't know of an efficient way to handle it.

The final output I would like to have is:

```
df1:

year  group  x_count  y_count  value
2018   a       2        5      103620
2019   a       0        4      98667.3
2020   a       3        0      97294.248
2018   b       0        0      53900
2019   b       1        0      56822
2020   b       1        0      59685.56
2018   c       5        1      495000
2019   c       3        0      497100
2020   c       2        5      420158
```

I achieved this by using:

```
starting_value-(starting_value*annual_group_cost)+(x_count*(individual_avg*x_benefit))-(y_count*(individual_avg*y_cost))
```

Comment: what is you expected output ?

Comment: I'm also not sure whats your expected output. But as for "taking the previous year's value", you can do df['value'].fillna(method='ffill')

Comment: I have updated the question with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Since subsequent new values are dependent upon previously calculated new values, this will need to involve (even if behind the scenes using e.g. `apply`) a for loop:

```
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    if np.isnan(df1.loc[i, 'value']):
        df1.loc[i, 'value'] = df1.loc[i-1, 'value'] #your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

You should merge the two tables together and then just do the functions on the data Series

```
hold = df_1.merge(df_2, on=['group']).fillna(0)

x = (hold.x_count*(hold.individual_avg*hold.x_benefit))
y = (hold.y_count*(hold.individual_avg*hold.y_cost))

for year in hold.year.unique():
    start = hold.loc[hold.year == year, 'starting_value']
    hold.loc[hold.year == year, 'value'] = (start-(start*annual_group_cost)+x-y)
    if year != hold.year.max():
       hold.loc[hold.year == year + 1, 'starting_value'] = hold.loc[hold.year == year, 'value'].values

hold.drop(['x_benefit', 'y_cost', 'individual_avg', 'starting_value'],axis=1)
```

Will give you

```
   year group  x_count  y_count       value
0  2018     a        2        5    103620.0
1  2019     a        0        4     98667.6
2  2020     a        3        0    97294.25
3  2018     b        0        0     53900.0
4  2019     b        1        0     55822.0
5  2020     b        1        0    57705.56
6  2018     c        5        1    491000.0
7  2019     c        3        0    490180.0
8  2020     c        2        5    416376.4
```